# Prevent asian characters using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to prevent the user from entering Asian characters (like **Japanese, Chinese**).

I tried using **$parsers** but i could notice that when i type some asian characters, function is not even called and is causing the issuee. But when i type, some English character, function gets executed as expected. Am i missing something ?

Also tried keypress and paste events but in Firefox, events are not triggered when i type asian characters.

How can i handle this functionality using angular JS?

Comment: Why? It sounds like you need to fix your backend to properly handle Unicode data.

Comment: Yes but i want to handle in both front and backend.

Comment: What problem are you having with Unicode characters?